# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in INSERT INTO SELECT with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, query, update, insert, group-by

I have the query of

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t2 (ID,P1,P2,Items) 
    SELECT ID,P1,P2,SUM(Items) 
    FROM t1 GROUP BY ID,P1,P2;
```

Since I need to run this query frequently to inspect changes in `t1`, I need to add

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t2.Items=SUM(t1.Items)
```

but it gives `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all functions you need to make a further select with the data

And please next time provide a minimal reproducible example, so that the answer can be doe quicker and with much less effort

> ```
> CREATE TABLe t2 (ID INT primary key,P1 INT,P2 INT ,Items INT )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1,1,1,1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe t1 (ID INT primary key,P1 INT,P2 INT ,Items INT )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,1,2,2)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT IGNORE INTO t2 (ID,P1,P2,Items) 
>     SELECT ID,P1,P2, t1sum
>     FROM
>     (SELECT ID,P1,P2,SUM(Items) t1sum
>     FROM t1 GROUP BY ID,P1,P2) t3
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t2.Items=t3.t1sum
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t2
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | P1 | P2 | Items
> -: | -: | -: | ----:
>  1 |  1 |  1 |     2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77f7d55429d133953020d6d7ccfb41c8)*

Comment: the hit of the first line was enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you can use the `VALUES(columnname)` syntax to access the value of the column to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (ID, P1, P2, Items) 
    SELECT ID, P1, P2, SUM(Items) 
    FROM t1 
    GROUP BY ID,P1,P2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t2.Items = VALUES(Items) ;
```